# Events not visible in GA4 reports

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have created tags in GTM but only one of them is visible in GA4 reports. The other ones fire and I can see them in realtime and also in debug view - but not in the reports.

I have waited for more than a week now.

I have created custom dimensions and inserted event parameters there.

I am wondering if I made a mistake by using the same parameter for different events? Or do I need unique parameters for each event?
Also does it matter that the tags that don’t show are for outbound links? Enhanced measurement is on.